# Can those paralyzed by the Hold Person spell be forcibly moved?

Tags: dnd-5e, conditions, forced-movement

Can a character shove a paralyzed person, forcing them to move?

Similarly, could a sorcerer cast the cantrip Gust to force the paralyzed person to move (without a Strength save)?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### Yes, they can be moved

The effects you describe do not force the creature to **move on its own**, but impose an outside force and **push** it (pulling would work similarly to pushing). These are two separate kinds of "forced movement", the former usually involving mind control or fear effects and the latter involving physical forces, whether summoned, evoked or mundane.

The description of a shove (PHB 195-6, emphasis mine)

> If you win the contest, you [..] **push** it 5 feet

*Gust* says (XGtE 157, emphasis mine)

> must succeed on a Strength saving throw or be
>   **pushed** up to 5 feet

Contrast this with a spell like *dissonant whispers* (PHB 234, emphasis mine)

> must immediately **use its reaction**, if available, to **move** as
>   far as its speed allows

or the "Flee" option of *command* (PHB 223, emphasis mine)

> The target spends its turn **moving** away from you

A paralyzed creature has a 0 movement speed and no actions available (incl. bonus or reactions) and thus cannot be forced to use them. Even if the spell would grant any of these, the condition would override that effect unless otherwise stated.

Note that the verb choice can be sometimes misleading. The verb "move" can be used both in a transitive (separate actor and subject), as well as an intransitive (actor and subject are the same) way. The above examples use it in an intransitive manner. An example of the transitive use would be the Grasp of Hadar eldritch invocation (XGtE 57, emphasis mine):

> you can **move that creature** in a straight line

In this case the creature performing the move is separate from the one suffering it, and it is thus an outside force that will work on even a paralyzed target.

Comment: @Medix2 The main distinction is, indeed, between moving *by yourself* and *being moved* and not between *move* and *push*, which I try to convey in the 1st paragraph. I will think about adding an example like yours.

Comment: @Medix2 Does this seem clearer to you?

Comment: yes, thank you for the clarification!

Comment: Worth explicitly mentioning that the effect of Hold Person is not some telekinetic grip that holds the person in place, but as the effect indicates, a paralysis that effectively seizes up the muscles of the afflicted person. As such, you could move them using any means available to you to move any non-resisting person. I.e., I think that the original question was borne from a misunderstanding of what/how exactly Hold Person created the effect.